# CSS: Target a button after an id

Tags: css

I have a table that has an id of 'table-noValues' or 'table-values' depending on if it has values or not. The tables both have a button with an id of 'calculateButton'.

I'm trying to get the css to be something like:

```
#table-noValues //add calculateButton here -- idk how to call the button here
{
  opacity: 0.65;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#table-values //calculateButton
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to call the button inside of the div. The button is a `<button>`, not an `<input>`

Comment: Could you add html part to your question to help us understand your problem.

Comment: @AlifJamaluddin I just want to know how to target a button inside of a div. Like #table-values button {...}. But that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You can do something like this `#div > button { ... }`

Comment: or you can add a class/id to the button tag like `<button id="btn-click"></button>` and can access like this `#btn-click`

Comment: @this.Believer It has an id of 'calculateButton'. Can I do like #table-values #calculateButton {...}?

Comment: if the #calculateButton is inside #table-values you can this `#table-values > #calculateButton { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

just use the ID you have on the button, and before it write the table ID like so

```
#table-noValues #calculateButton //when table has no values
{
  opacity: 0.65;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#table-values #calculateButton //when table has values
{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

and so it will give styles to the button depending on the table ID